# Why isn't an activity of mine responding to a change I made within my styles file?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to change the color of a textView of mine without changing all of it's other features. I created a style that this particular textView follows so t change the background of this textView, I simply changed the background of the style. However, it didn't make a difference. I'd appreciate if you told me why. 
XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
            <LinearLayout
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/question_textview"
                        style="@style/QuizCardQuestion"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/choice1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/QuizCardChoice.OddChoice"
                        android:background="@drawable/question_button"
                        android:onClick="addQuestionScorer"/>

                    <include layout="@layout/divider"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/choice2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/QuizCardChoice.EvenChoice"
                        android:background="@drawable/question_button"
                        android:onClick="addQuestionScorer"/>

                    <include layout="@layout/divider"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/choice3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/QuizCardChoice.OddChoice"
                        android:background="@drawable/question_button"
                        android:onClick="addQuestionScorer"/>

                    <include layout="@layout/divider"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/choice4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/QuizCardChoice.EvenChoice"
                        android:background="@drawable/question_button"
                        android:onClick="addQuestionScorer"/>

            </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles File:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/cardTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="QuizCardQuestion">
        <item name="android:background">#00d4ff</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#2F80ED</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="QuizCardChoice" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:gravity">left|start</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="QuizCardChoice.OddChoice" parent="QuizCardChoice">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="QuizCardChoice.EvenChoice" parent="QuizCardChoice">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="QuizChoiceDivider">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/divider_margin</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/divider_margin</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_gray</item>
    </style>

    <style name="QuizPageFooter">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CorrectAnswerBox" parent="QuizCardChoice">
        <item name="android:background">@color/correctAnswerGreen</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WrongAnswerBox" parent="QuizCardChoice">
        <item name="android:background">@color/wrongAnswerRed</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StatsTitles" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullStatistics" parent="StatsLabels">
    </style>

    <style name="StatsLabels" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StatsContent" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WelcomeHeadings" parent="StatsLabels">

    </style>

    <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/StatsLabels</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Picture of Error:

[image: picture]

(Notice:the purple box should be blue)